# Is it possible to specify number of nodes in hidden layer of SVM in OpenCV 3.1.0?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, svm

I was just curious to have a better control over outcome of the SVM.

Tried to search the documentation, but couldn't find a function that seems to do the same.

Comment: There are no hidden layers in SVM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could say that SVM does not have hidden nodes, but this is only partially true.

SVM, originally, were called Support Vector Networks (this is what Vapnik himself called them), and they were seen as a kind of neural networks with a single hidden layer. Due to the popularity of neural networks in this time, many people till this day use sigmoid "kernel" even though **it is rarely a valid Mercer's kernel** (only because NN community was so used to using it they started doing so even though it has no mathematical justification).

So is SVM a neural net or not? Yes, it **can be seen as a neural network**. In fact, many classifiers can be seen through such prism. However, what makes SVM really different is the way they are trained and parametrized. In particular, SVMs work with "activation functions" which are valid Mercer's kernels (they denote dot product in some space). Furthermore, **weights of the hidden nodes are equal to training samples**, thus you get the same amount of hidden units as you have training examples. During training, SVM, on its own, reduces number of hidden units through solving an optimization problem which "prefers" sparse solutions (removal of hidden units), thus ending up with the hidden layer consisting of the **subset of training samples**, we call them support vectors. To underline, this is not a classical view of SVMs, but it is **a valid perspective**, which might be more easy to understand by someone from NN community.

So can you control this number? Yes and no. No, because SVM needs all this hidden units to have a valid optimization problem, and it will remove all redundant ones on its own. Yes, because there is an alternative optimization problem, called nu-SVM, which uses nu-hyperparamer, which is **lower bound of support vectors**, thus **lower bound of hidden units**. You cannot, unfortunately, directly specify the upper bound.

**But I really need to!** If this is the case, you can go with approximate solutions which will follow your restriction. You can use `H`-dimensional sampler which approximate the kernel space explicitely (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html). One of such methods is Nystroem method. In short terms, if you want to have "`H` hidden units" you simply fit Nystroem model to produce `H` dimensional output, you transfrom your input data through it, and fit **linear SVM** on top. This, from mathematical perspective** is approximating true non-linear SVM with a given kernel, however quite slowly.